# mpdf not rendering styles from linked stylesheet

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using mpdf to generate a pdf from an HTML page but the stylesheet isn't working. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://swiftdigital.ltd.uk/pdf.css">
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->

<body id="the_pdf">

<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Logo" id="logo">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

If you scroll to the bottom of the CSS you will see a few styles that should be applied, for example wrapper should have a red border around it and so should the logo but none of these are being applied.

I am generating the PDF like so:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 0);
$mpdf->Output(pdf.pdf','F');
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Define "not working". Is it broken, or is it not applied at all? I see you are using bootstrap in your CSS, Bootstrap support in mPDF is not great.

Comment: The pdf gets generated but none of the styles from the stylesheet have been applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mPDF does not support `id` on `body` element. Remove `body#the_pdf` and `body#the_pdf` from your css selectors and your styles will be applied.

Other Bootstrap styles (specifically `font-family`) from your stylesheet are being applied correctly when I add eg. a heading and a paragraph to your example code.

See a page on [supported HTML attributes](https://mpdf.github.io/html-support/html-attributes.html) in the mPDF online manual.

Comment: it means that if the html block has a id tag tthen the mPDF not works? It's not is good 'cause almost all tags has a id actribuit. In this case, with to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the style sheet with WriteHtml() like this:

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);